# Better player Orientation issue in iOS latest version

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-video-player

I'm using a better player library, but in the new iOS version, after changing rotation, it is rolling back to the original rotation.

Who know this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the code also...